# Symfony Routing: When / where is _locale attribute set

Tags: php, symfony, localization, url-routing

I am working on a WebApp project using Symfony 2.8. I would like to add different languages to the page. Depending on the users locale all routes/URLs should be changed from `/some/url` to /locale/some/url`, e.g.`/en/some/url`.

Before adding the languages the main routing file looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Routes for the public pages -->
    <import
        resource="@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/public_routes.xml" />

    ...
</routes>
```

And the `public_routes.xml` has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="home" path="" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:home</default>
    </route>

    <route id="public_price" path="/price" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:price</default>
    </route>

    <route id="public_about" path="/about" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:about</default>
    </route>

    ...
</routes>
```

So far, so simple. Now I have added the following to the routing to add the localization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Home route to redirect to the right route -->
    <route id="home_redirect" path="" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:home</default>
    </route>

    <!-- Routes for the localized public pages -->
    <import
        resource="@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/public_routes.xml"
        prefix="/{_locale}" />

    ...
</routes>
```

So the import of the public pages was extended with `prefix="/{_locale}"` which automatically adds the current locale to all routes from `public_routes.xml`.

This works fine. I can now navigate to `/en`, `/en/price`, `/en/about`, etc.

However the still has to be an "empty" route. Otherwise the domain itself would have not valid route anymore. (**BTW**: Is there any difference between `path=""` and `path="/"`?)

This is handeled by the new `home_redirect` route with its controller:

```
public function homeAction(Request $request) {
    $locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale');
    if (!$locale) {
        // Try to get the preferred language from the request
        $locale = MySettings::getLanguage($request);               
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home', array('_locale' => $locale));
    } elseif (!MySettings::checkLanguage($locale)) {
        // Invalid Locale...
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:homepage.html.twig');
}
```

So if `_locale` is set for the request, the `homeAction` checks if the language is supported or throws an error. If `_locale` is not set, `homeAction` tries to get the current _locale from the request (e.g. from the browser accepted languages).

**THE PROBLEM:**
This solution above workes fine for all calles to `/`. In this case `_locale` is not set and thus the call is re-directed to `/someLocale/`, e.g. `/en/.

**BUT**: All calls to `/somepage` are also handled by `homeAction`. This is because `somepage` is interpreted as locale! Thus `homeAction` gets called with `$request->attributes->get('_locale') == 'somepage'`. This cannot work obviously.

So if someone calls the old URL `/about` instead of the new `/en/about`, the routing systems matches this call with route `home` with _locale `about` and the page is not found.

Where exactly does Symfony extracts `_locale` from the URL? Is it possible to intercept this extraction and make it a little bit smarter? E.g. to ignore all "locales" that are more than 2 letters long?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried settings a `requirements={'_locale': 'en|fr|...'}`? Might not be   a perfect solution but it should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply make use of `requirements` and `default` properties of routedefinition

so you can set {_locale} for all routes

```
  requirements:
    _locale: fr|en
  defaults: { _locale: fr}
```

in this yml example it defaults to "fr" if no _locale was given e.g `/`
and due to the requirements `about` would not be matched as _locale

Comment: Thank you for the hint! How/where exactly do I set `_locale` for **all** routes? Is it possible to use a value from `config.yml` instead of hardcoded `fr|en`?

Comment: sure just take the parameter notation : `{ _locale: %locale% }`

Comment: In which file does this information go?

Comment: @MathiasBader https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-in-yaml-xml-or-php-files